# How to correctly use CMake in default build task and why enabling WSL(2) changed VSCode task behavior?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, build, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I started using VSCode `Remote - WSL`extension and I immediately love it, but after enabling developer mode, windows virtualization, installing openSUSE and enabling WSL2 and maybe some other step that I forgot, following configuration stopped working:

```
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "C/C++: CMake build generate_numbers",
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build"
        },
        "command": "cmake make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .. && make -j`nproc`",
        "problemMatcher": [],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "presentation": {
            "echo": false,
            "reveal": "always",
            "focus": false,
            "panel": "shared",
            "showReuseMessage": true,
            "clear": true
        }
```

It's about line: `"command": "cmake make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .. && make -j`nproc`"`.

```
At line:1 char:40
+ cmake make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .. && make -j`nproc`
+                                        ~~
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine

The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command cmake make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .. && make -j`nproc`" failed to launch (exit code: 1).
```

It worked before the WSL shenanigans.

First, I don't like putting this complicated multi-command there, but it was the only accepted solution to run CMake as default build task.

So 2 questions:

1. Is there a more neat way how to run CMake build using the default build shortcut? I can click on `Build` in the bottom left part of VSCode used for CMake, but I want to use the default build task, so what is the correct way to make it a default build task?
2. If it was the only way, how to make it work again and why it stopped working?